# How much usable space will a 2TB+2TB+3TB+3TB btrfs filesystem have with data in RAID-1 mode?

Tags: raid, filesystems, btrfs

I have a pair of 3TB drives in a btrfs filesystem, and I wish to expand this filesystem by adding two more 2TB drives, using the `btrfs device add` command. Data in the current filesystem is mirrored in raid1 mode.

I am hoping the resulting filesystem will have 5TB usable capacity with all data in raid1 mode.

But, the [official wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices) states:

> When you have drives with differing sizes and want to use the full
>   capacity of each drive, you have to use the single profile for the
>   data blocks, rather than raid0.

*But*, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/290758/50856) suggests that there may have been a patch to use size-mismatched devices to full capacity with full data mirroring:

> There is a [quasi-round-robin patch](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg09832.html) in the pipeline to improve on this.
>   Of course, it is still impossible to pair all chunks on different
>   devices if you have a 500GB and a 2TB disk. The patch is intended more
>   for situations like 1 x 1TB + 2 x 500GB where each small disk should
>   prefer to mirror/stripe with the big disk instead of the other small
>   disk.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

According to the wiki you will end up with 5 TB after rebalancing it.

Keep in mind that Btrfs has no triple parity yet.

Take a look at the btrfs disk usage calculator: http://carfax.org.uk/btrfs-usage/

Comment: BTRFS has triple parity now https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/mkfs.btrfs#PROFILES